# Making Custom View in android with clickable every circle

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I would like to make a custom view in android such as :
[Circle must be clickable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MKRV.png)

[When user move next step dashed line must be change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwugI.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, be more specific. You should provide relevant snippets of code, layouts, etc. Have a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, have a detailed look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

check out this library

> https://github.com/iammert/MaterialIntroView

and work around it.